# Laravel bcrypt password not matching in lumen

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, jwt, lumen

I have created many users with laravel in the database with bcrypt() password, Now i am writing APIs in lumen where i am building JWT base authentication

My code looks like

```
$credentials = [
    'email' => $this->request->input('email'),
    'password' => $this->request->input('password'),
];

if (Auth::check($credentials)) {
    dd('success');
} else {
    dd('failed');
}
```

It fails, and goes to else section of the condition

Also i have tried Hash::check and it gives me false too

```
if (Hash::check($this->request->input('password'), $user->password)) {
    return response()->json([
        'token' => $this->jwt($user)
    ], 200);
}
```

**Note :** The password i am passing in the request is correct.

What am i doing wrong here, Whats missing

Comment: Are both of these separate apps? If so, bcrypt (if I'm not mistaken) uses APP_KEY from .env file to encrypt and you can have those mismatched.

Comment: @JCode Still doesn't works, The apps are changed

Comment: @JCode i have matched the app keys, Copied pasted, But still doesn't works

Comment: Have you confirmed that both Laravel and Lumen check hash and check passwords in the same way for the versions you're using?

Comment: @Gammer Did you solve it correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried `attempt()` instead of `check`

```
public function login(Request $request)
{
    $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');

    if ($token = $this->guard()->attempt($credentials)) {
        return $this->respondWithToken($token);
    }

    return response()->json(['error' => 'Unauthorized'], 401);
}
```

check [documentation](https://jwt-auth.readthedocs.io/en/docs/quick-start/)

You may need to edit your .env file with

```
AUTH_DRIVER=eloquent
AUTH_MODEL=\App\Models\User
AUTH_TABLE=users
```